# C# MS Access OleDb can't make write operations

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access, ado.net, oledb

I have a database in MS Access and I am trying to edit the table (db). SELECT works for me but edit operations like INSERT, SET and DELETE does not change anything.

I have this code below that deletes all rows. Initally there are 3 rows in the table, when I run the code output of affected rows is 3 but nothing is changed in the table.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DeleteRow();
        }
        
        static void DeleteRow()
        {
            OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
            connection.Open();
            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
            command.Connection = connection;
            command.CommandText = "DELETE FROM db";
            Console.WriteLine(command.ExecuteNonQuery());
            connection.Close();
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
```

I am using VS 2022 and when I run the query through server explorer it succesfully deletes the rows.

Comment: Do you COMMIT the transaction? (Is auto-commit expected?)

Comment: try command.CommandText = "DELETE * FROM db";

Comment: Did you really name your table `db` ?

Comment: Are you looking at the *correct* database? Where is the file stored? If it's a Content file in your project, the database file is copied into your `bin` folder on every build. Any modifications you make to the file inside `bin` will be lost on the next build

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos This works!! After I created a new database in bin folder and used it now there are no problems, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

From the [OleDBConnection documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.oledb.oledbconnection.close?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0):

> The Close method rolls back any pending transactions. It then releases
> the connection to the connection pool, or closes the connection if
> connection pooling is disabled.

You should try to commit the transaction before closing.

Comment: There's no transaction in the code